# how to use jquery .html() for fancybox content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, fancybox

my file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

{% include "submission-form.html" with section="photos" %}
<div class="commentables">
    {% load thumbnail %}

    {% for story in objects %}
        <div class="image {% if forloop.counter|add:"-1"|divisibleby:picsinrow %}left{% else %}{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:picsinrow %}right{% else %}middle{% endif %}{% endif %}">
            {% if story.image %}
                {% thumbnail story.image size crop="center" as full_im %}
                    <a rel="gallery" href="{% url post slug=story.slug %}">
                        <img class="preview" {% if story.title %} alt="{{ story.title }}" {% endif %} src="{{ full_im.url }}">
                    </a>
                {% endthumbnail %}
            {% else %}
                {% if story.image_url %}
                    {% thumbnail story.image_url size crop="center" as full_im %}
                        <a rel="gallery" href="{% url post slug=story.slug %}">
                            <img class="preview" {% if story.title %} alt="{{ story.title }}" {% endif %} src="{{ full_im.url }}">
                        </a>
                    {% endthumbnail %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

        </div>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".image a").click(function(){
            alert($(this).parent().html());
        });

       $(".image a").fancybox({
           title: $(this).attr("alt"),
           content: $(this).parent().html()
       });
    });
</script>
```

problem is, fancybox is loading the anchor's href's html, not the html I pass in for content, which alerts properly.

what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `$(this)` inside the fancybox (v1.3.x) function (it's a design issue), but inside any other jQuery method so try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".image a").bind("click",function (){
  var data = $(this).parent().html();
  var dataTitle = $(this).attr("alt");
  function newTitle(){return "<span>"+dataTitle+"</span>";}
  $.fancybox(data,{
   "titlePosition": "inside",
   "titleFormat": newTitle
  }); // fancybox
  return false;
 }); // bind
}); //ready
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will work:

```
   $(".image a").click(function (){
       $.fancybox($(this).parent().html(),{
           title: $(this).attr("alt")
       });
   });
```

Comment: Hm, it works here http://jsfiddle.net/hNfjC/ or isn't that what you expected? Maybe you do something else wrong?

Comment: that is what I expected, so I guess I'm doing something else wrong... but I don't know what.

Comment: @Colleen The only thing that is diffrent is the parent. Which element do you want to bring up in Fancybox? Its much eaiser if you provide the real DOM without the servercode, couse its not relevant for the question.

Comment: I wanted to bring up the <a>, but I'm thinking that because it is an <a>, it's loading the href. I found another way to do it, but I think I need to rethink the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Do you want to just display the image?

Comment: yes, but with the anchor so that if they click on the image in the lightbox, it goes to the page.